# How do I build a curved wall?

Tags: building, snir

On my latest MOC I want to build a round tower.

This is a minifig-scale build, and the tower is going to have a diameter of about 20/30 studs.

How should I go about building the "curved" wall of the tower?

Comment: There are many ways to make a curved wall. The smallest full circle shaped wall can be [made using 84 1x2 Bricks](http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/53073). For this scale you may require 1x1 cylinders/cones or hinges.

Comment: That looks a bit stressful ;)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Inspired by [Zhaph's wall](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/981/563), this one is made with 1x3 bricks.  It has a radius of 12 studs (24 studs diameter).

[image]

It is connected to the base by the last two studs on each end of the arc. The middle of the wall rests on tiles.  To complete the tower you can repeat this module 4 times and use 1x2 bricks to connect them (replacing the 1x1 end bricks).

This would not make a perfectly round wall, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Fantastic, cheers :)

Answer (score 30):

If you make a wall out of 1 x 2 bricks, where each layer overlaps by a 1-stud offset, and make the wall long enough, you can bend it into a smooth curve because of the manufacturing tolerance between Lego bricks.

[image: Example of wall with only 1x2 Bricks]
[By Eggy Pop from MOC Pages](http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/53073)

This particular wall uses rings of 84 bricks.

Comment: Cheers, that's a bit wider than I was looking for I think, and sounds a bit stressful for some of my older bricks.

Comment: I also want to make a castle tower (round) with 1x2 bricks, but how do you attach it to a baseplate or attach some sort of platform on top of it, to allow turrets and minifigs?

Comment: I wonder if you can have a smaller radius with 1x2 log bricks instead. The look might be great in any case.

Answer (score 28):

I managed to put together the following set-up for the beginnings of a slightly narrower tower:

[image: 1x2's and Cylinders]

This gives me a radius of about 7 studs if I go as tight as I can, giving a diameter of about 14/15 studs. I would have used [part:3062b] but I'm not that organised (yet), so went with [part:4589:378] instead.

I'll have to see what I can do with 1x3's and cylinders to get closer to 20-30 studs.

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of photos on brickshelf of similar builds, and lots of techniques that fans have used. You can either look in the "recent" list or use the search field to find what you're looking for. You'll have to collect pictures from shows and wip builds to source your preference to what resources you have at hand but there a lot of pictures for future reference. I've learned more in five months of looking at that site than in ten years of experimenting at home!