# Working with Curved Bricks

Tags: building, compatibility

I'm hoping to stack [curved bricks](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48092#T=C). There are two slots along the edge to allow the bricks to be set on plates. These become unsightly when the bricks are stacked atop each other. Has anyone seen any techniques to fill these gaps while maintaining the general curve shape?

Answer (score 4):

One possible "technique" could simply be to use the [round wall panels](http://brickset.com/parts?query=30562) of the same diameter:

[image: 30562]

This part has the same stud recesses at the bottom, but since it's much taller, they won't appear as frequently in your model (or at all if this part alone provides the height that you need).

This obviously has a number of disadvantages, the largest being that you're stuck with less flexibility over the color as you can't use stripes of different colors.

You might also be interested in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/976/how-do-i-build-a-curved-wall) that provides other ideas for building curved walls.

Comment: I want to give you a shoutout for your work this week. We're getting some great results and user activity!