# Simple way to build large circular plates?

Tags: building, moc, hero-factory, system

I was wondering if there is a simple way to create a large circle or circular plates. I want to build a MOC of the Hero Factory assembly tower (*In LDD first*) but most of the pieces that form circles don't give enough clearance for a decently sized CCBS model. I was wondering if there were any bricks or techniques that would help for this specific MOC.

Comment: Similar question: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/976/how-do-i-build-a-curved-wall

Comment: In the [accepted answer in that question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/995/15028), you can see a wall made of [these parts](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3622#T=C), [these parts](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b#T=C), and [these parts](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3794b#T=C). Try building it in LDD.

Comment: TL;DR: How to make a *big* circle-shaped **PLATE**, right?

Comment: ...and if so, HOW big a platform? what's 'decently sized' mean? just some rough figure, any unit will do...

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you mean by CCBS? A quick google search tells that it stands for "Contract Contingent on Buyer Sale" but I'm not sure if that fits into your question. I might as well remove the acronym if no response comes soon enough.

Comment: @mindstormsboi: it's [Character_and_Creature_Building_System](https://en.brickimedia.org/wiki/Character_and_Creature_Building_System)

Comment: @Uli when I said "decently sized" I was thinking around a size to fit a set like Breez: 2227 or Surge: 44008 positioned to take up as much space as possible space since I want to treat this like an easel but for creating CCBS sets.

Comment: @MedicinalMan [Surge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=44008-1&name=Surge&category=%5BHero%20Factory%5D%5BHeroes%5D#T=I) seems to be 17 cm wide and 23 cm tall, so let's say at least ø 20 cm for the platform? That's 25 [studs](http://studs.sariel.pl). Or still bigger? As for the easel: will it be a fixed platform or a turntable, like say a pottery wheel...?

Comment: @Uli I'd need it to be larger, as I plan to have the platform go up and inward off of the base, as well as mount some CCBS  parts on the walls (In order to mimic the tower in the show) so I'd need around 3 studs of space in each direction.

Comment: @MedicinalMan Is it this one? [LEGO Hero Factory - Full Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFrS-byDInQ&t=0m43s) at 0:43, seen from above...

Comment: @Uli That's exactly what I meant with the platform shape but I also wanted to make enough space to mount parts on the wall like in the Breakout mini-movie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTDpEJJVSLw

Answer (score 3):

The largest truely round base plates in the LEGO system fit in a 8x8 square. You can build them from two [LegoPlate, Round Half 4 x 8](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6003&name=Plate,%20Round%20Corner%206%20x%206&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C) or from four quarters.

For a bigger (and thicker!) base plate there is a Duplo version of the above mentioned base plate, fitting into a 16x16 studs LEGO system square: [LegoDuplo, Plate Round Corner 4 x 8 Double](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=29304&name=Duplo,%20Plate%20Round%20Corner%204%20x%208%20Double&category=%5BDuplo,%20Plate%5D#T=C)

EDIT: For a thicker base, you can use [these bricks: Brick, Round Corner 10 x 10 with Slope 33 Edge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58846&idColor=2#T=C&C=2). They make a base fitting into a 20x20 square.

Comment: What about https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6162&name=Brick,%20Round%20Corner%2012%20x%2012&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}

Comment: @molot Nice finding. I wonder how round this brick is, it seems¹ that for 4 studs it is just straight before the round contour starts. ¹I don't have one of them in my collection

Comment: I don't have one either, so let's just leave it in comment for now, maybe someone else will be able to tell. Another question is, how round @medicinalman really needs it to be.